# Filter query based by selected options

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to create a Filter search in my app where you have the following models:

- Visitor
- Attributeresponse
  [image]

One Visitor can have many Attributeresponse used for saving details such as name, last name, locale, and many many more

**What I am trying to accomplish**

[image]

As shown in the image, I would like to retrieve *Visitors* who have Attributeresponse with the column name = "name" and its value = "hector22" AND at the same time column name = "locale" and its value = "es"

In other words, Retrieve a Visitor with name = hector22 and locale = es.

This is what I have at the moment in SQL:

```
select
  *
from
  `visitors`
where
  `bot_id` = '1255'
  and exists (
    select
      *
    from
      `attributeresponses`
    where
      `visitors`.`id` = `attributeresponses`.`visitor_id`
      and (
        `attributeresponses`.`attribute_name` = 'name'
        and `attributeresponses`.`value` = 'hector22'
      )
      and (
        `attributeresponses`.`attribute_name` = 'locale'
        and `attributeresponses`.`value` = 'es'
      )
  )
order by
  `visitors`.`id` desc
limit
  10 offset 0
```

And this is in Eloquent

```
            // retrieve visitors related to filters
            $visitors = Visitor::where('bot_id', $data['bot_id'] )
            // ->with(['properties' => function($topQuery) use ($data, $filters) {
            ->whereHas('properties', function($query) use ($filters, $data) {
                
            foreach( $filters as $key => $filter ){


                    $query->where(function($q) use ($filter) {
                                                        
                            $q->where('attributeresponses.attribute_name', $filter['property'] );

                            if($filter['operator'] == 1){
                                // IS equal
                                $q->where('attributeresponses.value', $filter['value'] );
                            }else if($filter['operator'] == 2){
                                // IS NOT equal
                                $q->where('attributeresponses.value', '!=', $filter['value']);                        
                            }else if($filter['operator'] == 3 && (is_numeric($filter['value'])) ){
                                // IS greater than
                                $q->where('attributeresponses.value', '>', $filter['value']);                        
                            }else if($filter['operator'] == 4 && (is_numeric($filter['value'])) ){
                                // IS less than
                                $q->where('attributeresponses.value', '<', $data['filters']['value']);                                                
                            }    
                        });


               


            }     
            })                        


            ->limit( 10 )
            ->offset( ( $data['paginate'] == 0 ? 0 : $data['paginate'] *10) )
            ->orderBy( 'visitors.id', 'desc' )
            ->get();
```

I am still struggling with this, because it is not bringing any records and I do have a Visitor that has a record under Attributeresponse with name = "name" and value = "hector22" and this same Visitor has another Attributeresponse with name = "locale" and value = "es"

I am sorry if I couldn't make myself clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested (obviously), but just something to think about

```
select v.*
  from visitors v
  join attributeresponses r
    on r.visitor_id = v.id
where v.bot_id = 1255
   and (r.attribute_name,r.value) IN (('name','hector22'),('locale','es'))
Group 
    by v.id
having Count(distinct (r.attribute_name,r.value)) = 2
 order 
     by v.id desc
limit 10 
offset 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help, so far it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Your current query will try to get visitors which have an attribute with name `name` and `locale` at the same time, which is impossible, instead you could `OR` them like below:

```
// retrieve visitors related to filters
$visitors = Visitor::where('bot_id', $data['bot_id'] )
    // ->with(['properties' => function($topQuery) use ($data, $filters) {
    ->whereHas('properties', function($query) use ($filters, $data) {   
        foreach( $filters as $key => $filter) {

            $query->orWhere(function($q) use ($filter) {                                            
                $q->where('attributeresponses.attribute_name', $filter['property'] );
                if($filter['operator'] == 1){
                    // IS equal
                    $q->where('attributeresponses.value', $filter['value'] );
                }else if($filter['operator'] == 2){
                    // IS NOT equal
                    $q->where('attributeresponses.value', '!=', $filter['value']);                        
                }else if($filter['operator'] == 3 && (is_numeric($filter['value'])) ){
                    // IS greater than
                    $q->where('attributeresponses.value', '>', $filter['value']);                        
                }else if($filter['operator'] == 4 && (is_numeric($filter['value'])) ){
                    // IS less than
                    $q->where('attributeresponses.value', '<', $data['filters']['value']);                                                
                }    
            });
        }    
    }, count($filters));                        


    ->limit( 10 )
    ->offset( ( $data['paginate'] == 0 ? 0 : $data['paginate'] *10) )
    ->orderBy( 'visitors.id', 'desc' )
    ->get();
```

This will `OR` all the filters but will also require the number of related results to equal `count($filters)` i.e. all the filters to have matched something.

Comment: I appreciate your help, it seems to work if I place the having clause that Strawberry mentioned!